# How to get rid of 'GLIBCXX_3.4.9 not found error'?

Tags: linux, gcc, dependencies, glibc, glib

I am building a redistrbutable .so file.

However when my users try to use it they get the dreaded `/usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6: version GLIBCXX_3.4.9' not found` error.

Doing an objdump, it seems its this particular symbol in my binary that is causing the issue:
`_ZSt16__ostream_insertIcSt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIT_T0_ES6_PKS3_l@@GLIBCXX_3.4.9`

How do i tell my gcc/g++ to compile/link against an older version of GLIBXX so that my users dont get this error?

Or is the only way out of this conundrum to install a separate older version of linux which has an GLIBXX?

Comment: You could try statically linking to the C/C++ libraries.

Comment: i cant. my library is closed source and static linking would apply the gpl license to it

Comment: Are you sure?  http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/faq.html#faq.license.what

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How do i tell my gcc/g++ to compile/link against an older version of GLIBXX so that my users dont get this error?

There is *no* way to do that. Your only choices are:

1. build with older `g++` version, or
2. link `libstdc++.a` statically into your shared library, and *hide* its symbols (this may also have licensing implications, check with your lawyer).
3. package your version of `libstdc++.so.6` together with your library, and ask users who have an older version to arrange to pick up your newer version instead (also has licensing implications, but I believe these are easier to satisfy).

Answer (score 0):

You are building *for* GLIBCXX_3.4.9, hence your users *also* need to have at least GLIBCXX_3.4.9.

Comment: i know. thing is most of my users dont. so i need to know how to tell gcc to build against a lower version. does that entail just passing extra arguments or installing a whole bew, old version of linux?